# Ruby: Net::HTTP.start issue

Tags: ruby, http, networking, net-library

I've got this code (roughly):

```
parsed_url = URI.parse(url_string)
puts "before Net::HTTP.start block"
response = Net::HTTP.start(parsed_url.host, parsed_url.port) { |http|
  puts "inside Net::HTTP.start block"
  http.read_timeout = 10
  http.get(parsed_url.path)
}
```

When I execute the code against a url that timesout in the browser, it never gets into the block. Any other situation it works perfectly. Is there some behavior on the start method that I don't see? I was assuming that the connection wouldn't be opened at all until the http.get(parsed_url.path) statement so I'm confused why this code more doesn't execute...

thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you running inside a virtual machine? What platform?

Comment: I am! Ubuntu client via VirtualBox on a win7 64bit host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Net:HTTP.start` calls `do_start` which then calls `connect` (both of them are private methods):

http://apidock.com/ruby/Net/HTTP/connect

The first 3 lines are

```
D "opening connection to #{conn_address()}..."
s = timeout(@open_timeout) { TCPSocket.open(conn_address(), conn_port()) }
D "opened"
```

and while I can't seem to find docs for the `timeout` method, this could be your culprit.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the [Net::HTTP class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-start) reads

> Opens TCP connection and HTTP session.

So when you call `Net::HTTP.start`, the connection is made and if you cannot access the given URL, then a `Timeout::Error` is thrown inside the `start` method and the code inside your block is indeed never executed.